# Как вывести сообщение об ошибке после ввода цифры?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте!

Помогите, плз, кто знает. У меня есть программа, которая генерирует строку по моим правилам. Например, я ввожу свои правила 121213456, все генерируется правильно, но если ввести 121213456321, то цифры 321 должны записаться в массив и я должен получить сообщение, что срока сгенерирована полностью. Можно как-нибудь сделать, чтобы после цифры 6 вводишь цифры и получаешь сообщение о ошибке? Заранее спасибо. Код предоставлен

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
char s[20], d[20], r[20];
int res, z = 0, flag = 0;

void pravilo1(char *s)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        if (s[i] == 'S') {
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                d[j] = s[j];
            for (j = i; j < strlen(s) + 2; j++)
                d[j + 2] = s[j + 1];
            d[i] = '1';
            d[i + 1] = 'A';

        }
    }
    for (j = 0; j <= strlen(d); j++)
        s[j] = d[j];
}

void pravilo2(char *s)
{
    int i, j, k;

    for (k = 0; k <= 40; k++) {
        if ((s[k] != 'S') || (s[k] != 'A'))
            flag = 0;
        if (flag == 1) {
            printf("stroka sgenerirovana polnostiyu \n");
            res = 1;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
        if (s[i] == 'A') {
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                d[j] = s[j];
            for (j = i; j < strlen(s) + 3; j++)
                d[j + 2] = s[j + 1];
            d[i] = '2';
            d[i + 1] = 'a';
            d[i + 2] = 'S';
        }

    for (j = 0; j <= strlen(d); j++)
        s[j] = d[j];
}

void pravilo3(char *s)
{
    int i, j, k;

    {
        for (k = 0; k <= 40; k++)
            if ((s[k] != 'A') || (s[k] != 'S'))
                flag = 0;
        if (flag == 1) {
            printf("stroka sgenerirovana polnostiyu \n");
            res = 1;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
        if (s[i] == 'S') {
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                d[j] = s[j];
            for (j = i; j < strlen(s) + 3; j++)
                d[j + 2] = s[j + 1];
            d[i] = '1';
            d[i + 1] = 'a';
            d[i + 2] = 'S';
        }

    for (j = 0; j <= strlen(d); j++)
        s[j] = d[j];
};

void pravilo4(char *s)
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (k = 0; k <= 40; k++) {
        if ((s[k] != 'A') || (s[k] != 'S'))
            flag = 0;
        if (flag == 1) {
            printf("stroka sgenerirovana polnostjw \n");
            res = 1;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
        if (s[i] == 'S') {
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                d[j] = s[j];
            for (j = i; j < strlen(s) + 2; j++)
                d[j + 2] = s[j + 1];
            d[i] = '2';
            d[i + 1] = 'A';
        }

    for (j = 0; j <= strlen(d); j++)
        s[j] = d[j];
}

void pravilo5(char *s)
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (k = 0; k <= 40; k++) {
        if ((s[k] != 'A') || (s[k] != 'S'))
            flag = 0;
        if (flag == 1) {
            printf("stroka sgenerirovana polnostjw \n");
            res = 1;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
        if (s[i] == 'S') {
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                d[j] = s[j];
            for (j = i; j < strlen(s) + 2; j++)
                d[j + 2] = s[j + 1];
            d[i] = '1';
            d[i + 1] = 'S';
        }

    for (j = 0; j <= strlen(d); j++)
        s[j] = d[j];
}

void pravilo6(char *s)
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        if (s[i] == 'S') {
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                d[j] = s[j];
            for (j = i; j < strlen(s); j++)
                d[j] = s[j + 1];
        }

        for (j = 0; j <= strlen(d); j++)
            s[j] = d[j];
    };
    for (k = 0; k <= 40; k++) {
        if ((s[k] != 'A') || (s[k] != 'S'))
            flag = 0;
        if (flag == 1) {
            printf("stroka sgenerirovana polnostiyu \n");
            res = 1;
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    int k = 0, i = 0;
    clrscr();
    s[0] = 'S';
    s[1] = '\0';
    printf("Vvedite pravilo:");
    gets(r);
    while (r[k] != '\0') {
        switch (r[k]) {
        case '1':{
                pravilo1(s);
                if ((flag == 1) && (z == 0)) {
                    printf
                        ("stroka sgenerirovana polnostiyu \n");
                    z = 1;
                }
            }
            break;
        case '2':{
                pravilo2(s);
                if ((flag == 1) && (z == 0)) {
                    printf
                        ("stroka sgenerirovana polnostiyu \n");
                    z = 1;
                }
            }
            break;
        case '3':{
                pravilo3(s);
                if ((flag == 1) && (z == 0)) {
                    printf
                        ("stroka sgenerirovana polnostiyu \n");
                    z = 1;
                }
            }
            break;
        case '4':{
                pravilo4(s);
                if ((flag == 1) && (z == 0)) {
                    printf
                        ("stroka sgenerirovana polnostiyu \n");
                    z = 1;
                }
            }
            break;
        case '5':{
                pravilo5(s);
                if ((flag == 0) && (z == 0)) {
                    printf
                        ("stroka sgenerirovana polnostiyu \n");
                    z = 1;
                }
            }
            break;
        case '6':{
                pravilo5(s);
                if ((flag == 0) && (z == 0)) {
                    printf
                        ("stroka sgenerirovana polnostiyu \n");
                    z = 1;
                }
            }
            break;
            if (res == 1)
                goto B1;
        }
        k++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= 40; i++)
        if ((s[i] == 'A') || (s[i] == 'S'))
            flag = 1;
    if (flag == 1)
        printf("stroka sgenerirovana ne polnostiyu \n");

 B1:
    puts(s);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Объясните, что должна делать ваша программа, что за правила... Слишком большой код - что бы понять что она должна сделать...

Comment: Она генерирует строку, например, по моему варианту это `12а12а11а12а12`. Я сделал 6 правил, с помощью которых ее можно получить, 121213456, 6 уходит в бесконечность и если ввести после 6 еще цифры, должно просто выводить сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 1):

Так ты пройди по основному массиву сразу после чтения...
И если встретилась цифра 6, то смотрим есть ли чего-нибудь ещё после неё... 
Если есть ставим флажок говорим ошибка и заканчиваем работу...
=)